# Logstash is not creating the Index form the default template or the temple name provided in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

i am trying to process my logs with custom template svlogs but Inex is not getting created on the go based on my template .i am facing below error

`"error"=>{"type"=>"index_not_found_exception", "reason"=>"no such index", "resource.type"=>"index_expression", "resource.id"=>"svlogs-2016.12.29", "index_uuid"=>"_na_", "index"=>"svlogs-2016.12.29"}`

My output is

```
output {
elasticsearch {
    hosts => [ "192.168.254.129:9200" ]
    user => "logstash"
    password => "selva123"
    template_name => "svlogs"
    index => "svlogs-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
    }}
```

my template is :

> 

```
curl -XPUT  '192.168.254.129:9200/_template/svlogs?pretty' -d'
{
  "template": "svlogs*",
  "settings": {
    "number_of_shards": 1
  },
  "mappings" : {
  "_default_" : {
   "properties" : {
    "MSGID" : {"type": "integer" },
    "debug" : {"type": "string"  , "index" : "not_analyzed" },
    "Error" : { "type" : "string", "index" : "not_analyzed"  },
    "client" : { "type" : "string"  },
    "eno" : { "type" : "integer" },
    "login" : { "type" : "string" },
    "message" : { "type" : "string" },
    "pid" : { "type" : "integer" },
    "process" : { "type" : "string" },
    "sv_date" : { "type": "date", "format": "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:SS yyyy"},
    "type"  : { "type" : "string" }
   }
  }
 }
}'
```

i was expecting logstash will create teh Index based on the temple given

Actually it was working till i installed x-pack . Theni have resolved all my privilege related issues , Now i need to create the index manually to make my logstash work . i tried added managae_temaple as "false" still no help .

Please guide Thanks in advance .

Comment: Have you tried to also set `template_overwrite` to true as well (it's false by default)?

Comment: Yes . but no change :(

Comment: Hi Val , Issue got resolved after i commented below line in elasticsearch.yml

Comment: #action.auto_create_index: .security,.monitoring*,.watches,.triggered_watches,.watcher-history*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue got resolved after i commented below line in elasticsearch.yml

```
#action.auto_create_index: .security,.monitoring*,.watches,.triggered_watches,.watcher-‌​history*
```